# Java/HtmlUnit - How to get an HtmlImage from an HtmlImageInput?

Tags: java, html, image, htmlunit

I've got an image on an html page that is also an input.

```
<input type="image" src=...
```

I couldn't care less about clicking the image. I want to save the image to a File. It seems to be impossible which seems ridiculous. I tried casting from `HtmlImageInput` to `HtmlImage` but I just get an error. How can I do this? Do I need to switch from HtmlUnit to something else? I don't care what I need to do to get this done.

By the way, I tried using selenium and taking a screenshot but it's taking a screenshot of the wrong area. Tried multiple different xpaths to the same element and it always takes the wrong screenshot.

Comment: You have make a `form` with that input inside it, then process it server-side to do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Similar to `HtmlImage`, `.saveAs(File)` has been just [added](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/14419) to `HtmlImageInput`.

BTW, if you can't use latest snapshot, then you can use:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080");
    HtmlImageInput input = page.querySelector("input");
    URL url = page.getFullyQualifiedUrl(input.getSrcAttribute());
    final String accept = webClient.getBrowserVersion().getImgAcceptHeader();
    final WebRequest request = new WebRequest(url, accept);
    request.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", page.getUrl().toExternalForm());
    WebResponse imageWebResponse =  webClient.loadWebResponse(request);
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the image changes every time its url is reloaded?

Comment: I believe so, since the JavaScript would change the 'src' attribute, and so the URL would change.

Comment: The image itself is an aspx file so JavaScript isn't changing the url. It's the same everything but when reloaded the image changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HtmlImage codeImg = (HtmlImage) findElement(xpath, index);
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        is = codeImg.getWebResponse(true).getContentAsStream();
        data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("get img stream meets error :", e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
    if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
        String errorMessage = String.format("downLoad img verify code with xpath %s failed.", xpath);
        throw new EnniuCrawlException(TargetResponseError.ERROR_RESPONSE_BODY, errorMessage);
    }
    String base64Img = Base64Utils.encodeToString(data);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer